# Understrap 'require is not defined'

Tags: node.js, wordpress, gulp

I'm using the [Understrap theme](https://github.com/holger1411/understrap) for my Wordpress project. I created a simple custom .js file to add to my project but I'm getting a '**require is not defined**' error.

custom .js file

```
var express = require('express');
var moment = require('moment');
var app = express();
var m = moment();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

     m.set({'year': 2017, 'month': 5, 'day': 29});
     //res.send(moment().format('YYYY/M/D'));
     var today = document.getElementById('today');
     today.innerHTML = moment().format('YYYY/M/D');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs is a server side language, you cannot use require in browser side unless you use browserify or webpack. And also you cannot use express in browser because it's a server side framework, as you are using a theme for wordpress, I don't think you need to use nodejs at all, just write the plain js.